# 2d arraylists in java (why are the collections the same eventually)

Tags: java

I have a 2D `ArrayList`. The `ArrayList` contains 10 `ArrayList`s. I tried the following code:

This is the main 2D `ArrayList`. Inside the main `ArrayList` there are10 `ArrayList`s:

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Items>> arrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Items>>();
```

Here I tried to create a copy of one of the `ArrayList` (`selectedRow` is just a number which says which `ArrayList` I get)

```
ArrayList<Items> newList = new ArrayList<Items>(arrayList.get(selectedRow));
```

After that I create another `ArrayList`:

```
   ArrayList<Items> changeList = new ArrayList<Items>(it.returnTheNewArrayList(newList,randomItem));
```

Then in another class I created this method. The purpose of this method is to change an attribute of one of the objects.

```
public  ArrayList<Items> returnTheNewArrayList(ArrayList<Items> a,int item){

  int randomBin = r.nextInt(50);

    for(Items i:a){

        if(item==i.itemIds()){

            while(randomBin==i.bins()){
                randomBin = r.nextInt(50);

            }
            i.setBin(randomBin);

        }

    }
return a;

}
```

Finally, I set the new ArrayList in the 2D ArrayList

```
arrayList.set(whichList, changeList);
```

This is the procedure. I have find out, that when I run this procedure, both `newList` and `changeList` are the same. In both of these `ArrayLists` I'm saving the change I did in the method `returnTheNewArrayList` (I found out it with the debugging). But I want to change only one (the `changeList`).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You have to make a clone of the object itself; now you are putting the same object in a copy of the list. BTW `Items` is a strange name for a class; if one object of this type is one item, then better call the class `Item`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lists contain *references* to objects. When you call `i.setBin(...)` that's (presumably) making a change to the object itself.

Each list has an independent copy of the references - so you could remove an element from one list without affecting the other - but they're *only* references.

Imagine you gave two people clipboards, with the same list of home addresses on. One person went and painted the front door of every house list on their clipboard red, then the second person visited all the same houses. The second person would see red doors, wouldn't they? It's the same thing here. **The lists contain references, not objects.**

If you want the lists to be *completely* independent, you'll need to populate them with references to *different* objects.

EDIT: I've just noticed that you'll *also* need to change your `returnTheNewArrayList` method, which actually isn't even creating a new `ArrayList` in the first place!

```
public ArrayList<Items> returnTheNewArrayList(ArrayList<Items> a,int item) {
    // Stuff which doesn't change the value of a...

    return a;
}
```

Again, the value of `a` is just a *reference* to the list... so when you return the same reference back, you're not returning a *new* `ArrayList` at all.

You really need to understand how references and objects work in Java - it's absolutely *crucial* to working with the language.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to extend an answer that was already sufficient.

Comment: and `Collections.copy(List dest, List src)` would be helpful to use

Comment: @TheNail: It really wasn't, as I hadn't paid enough attention to the *critical* flaw in `returnTheNewArrayList`! But thanks for the vote of confidence :)

Answer (score 2):

Inside of the `returnTheNewArrayList` method, you first need to clone `a`.  Otherwise you will be modifying the original ArrayList and the original `Items`.  Jon did a nice job of explaining why, so I won't go into it here.  Your code could look something like:

```
ArrayList<Items> clone = new ArrayList<Items>(a.size());
for(Items item: a) clone.add(item.clone());

//modify clone here

return clone;
```

Since you've written the `Items` class yourself, you will need to implement the `Cloneable` interface yourself.

See the clone method's [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29) for more information.

Comment: Here in your example you wrote: item.clone().but for the object item i can't find the method clone().I mean that when i write it hits me an error.Why?

Comment: @Alex If you wrote `Items` yourself, you have to implement `clone` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The newList and changeList are not the same (not == ) but their content are identical.

Your "Item" objects are passed by reference that's why the two lists references the same Items.

To get a brand new reference you should create a new instance of Item in method returnTheNewArrayList (10 new instances for 10 new references.)

```
public  ArrayList<Items> returnTheNewArrayList(ArrayList<Items> a,int item){
//create a new List
ArrayList<Items> newList = new ArrayList<Items>();
int randomBin = r.nextInt(50);
    for(Items oldItem:a){
        // make a copy of Item to get a new instance of Item for the new List
        Item newItem = new Item(oldItem);
        if(item==newItem.itemIds()){

            while(randomBin==newItem.bins()){
                randomBin = r.nextInt(50);

            }
            newItem.setBin(randomBin);

        }

        newList.add(newItem);

    }
return newList;

}
```